# In Play Morphia how do I manage updates?

Tags: playframework, morphia

If I have a call like "Update(JsonObject body)" and the intent is to take an existing document and update some of the document but not all, how does that work?

```
{ 
  _id: "12345",
  name: "my name",
  email: "me@here.org",
  privatefield: "secret data"
}
```

If the above is the currently stored document and the update is only allowed to contain "name" and "email", how can that work?

```
body = { 
  _id: "12345",
  name: "my name",
  email: "me@here.org"
}

static public void Update(JsonObject body){
   Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().create();
   MyModel m = gs.fromJson(body, MyModel.class);
   // this call erases "privatefield" from the document
   m.Save();
}
```

If I use the Gson().fromJson(...) call, the object is created missing the privatefield value. Now I need to manually merge them. What if the updated email value is null on purpose? How does the merge work?

I get the feeling I need to manually map all this stuff which seems so anti-play.

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an issue to request a feature in PlayMorphia to solve this problem:

https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/issues/94